# How to display data from a Javascript file in ionic?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Javascript and Ionic and I would like to know how to display the name of my user in the app itself.

1. I have a connection to Firebase that works fine
2. Here is the code of js file :

   ```
   var userId = '-KcntxrTC1eZjrkyycn4';
   return firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
       var displayName = snapshot.val().name;
       console.log(displayName);
       // ...
   });
   ```
3. My html file is controlled by the controller where this code is.
4. The console log renders "Sebastien" so it works
5. When I write `{{displayName}}` in my html document, nothing shows up.

What am I missing ?

**EDIT - ADD CODE**

Here is the code of my controller :

```
.controller('accountController',['$scope', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', '$document', '$state', function($scope, $firebaseArray, CONFIG, $document, $state) {

  var userId = '-KcntxrTC1eZjrkyycn4';
  return firebase.database().ref('/accounts/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
  var displayName = snapshot.val().name;
  $scope.displayName = snapshot.val().name;
  console.log(displayName);
  // ...


  });
}])
```

Here is the code of my HTML document :

```
<!-- *profile-name / name profile -->
                <h3 class="profile-name">{{diplayName}}</h3>
```

The thing is that I get the name to show up in the console as soon as I log in but when I visit the page that is controlled by the actual controller, it doesn't pick it up. Like it didn't understand that it has to take the data from Firebase.

Comment: You have to place the properties you want to use in your views on your `$scope` object: `$scope.displayName = snapshot.val().name;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is because angular does not pick up the database read because it is happening outside of its `$digest` cycle. If you wrap your code in an `$apply`, it will probably work:

```
firebase.database()
    .ref('/accounts/' + userId)
    .once('value')
    .then(function(snapshot) {
        var displayName = snapshot.val().name;
        console.log(displayName);

        $scope.$apply(function() {
            $scope.displayName = displayName;
        });
    // ...
});
```

Note: Remove the `return` statement. A controller should not return anything.

Answer (score 2):

whatever you want to show in view, you need to add in `$scope` angular service

**JavaScript**

```
$scope.data = {
  fName: "Sanjay",
  lName: "Nishad"
}
```

**HTML**

```
<p> {{data.fName}} </p>
<p> {{data.lName}} </p>
```

In your case:
You don't need to declare `var displayName = snapshot.val().name;` just add in `$scope`

```
$scope.displayName = snapshot.val().name;
```

or

```
$scope.displayData = snapshot.val();
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your time but it is still not working, it writes the value in the console but still doesn't show up anything...

Comment: What is showing? And which element are you using? May be that element clear by some other JS code or spell mistake

Comment: I edited my initial code, and nothing is showing at all, not even an error in the console, nothing. It just leaves a blank space instead of the name.

Comment: try once `$scope.$apply()` after assigning the value

Comment: Thank you very much, indeed, it worked like a charm !